# SD card using SPI initialization stm32f303 issue with CMD0

Tags: initialization, spi, stm32ldiscovery

I am sending the correct command and I can see it on the scope.However, I don't get 0x01 response(I keep getting 0xff) from SDcard(SDHC)(SanDisk Ultra 40MB/s ...16GB) I am using the following code:

```
uint8_t cmd0[6]={0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x95};
uint8_t dumb=0xff;
FATFS_CS_HIGH;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &dumb, 1, 10);
   while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
}

FATFS_CS_LOW;

HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, cmd0, 6, 10);
while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &dumb, 1, 10);
   while (HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
}
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &c, 1, 10);// I keep getting 0xff
```

Here is the configuration I am using for SPI from cubeMX
[image: SPI from cubeMX]